# Why does android app crash after adding button for launching new activity?

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

real noob over here. I'm trying to create a second activity to launch the second layout. The instant I try adding the setOnClockListener, launching the app goes to a dark screen, never really loads up, then crashes.

There are two layouts: activity_main.xml and activity_camcord.xml. I posted the MainActivty, second activity CamcordActivity and the Manifest.

Please let me know whatever else I can do to make this informative enough

**Main Activity**

```
package com.notebook.ksen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Retrieve the button object
        Button imageButtonCamCord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCamCord);
        //Attach the Listener
        imageButtonCamCord.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , CamcordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    return true;
}
```

}

**SecondActivity**

```
package com.notebook.ksen;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class CamcordActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camcord);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camcord, menu);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camcord);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.notebook.ksen.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    <activity android:name=".CamcordActivity" android:label="camcord"/> </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: For future reference, learn all you can about the logcat -- it's your number one line of defense.

Comment: @323go Not sure how to use it, for example, after taking the current solution for avoid app from crashig, how can I figure out why the imagebutton doesnt launch the next layout? using the logcat

Comment: It'll help you debug the crash. You can set a breakpoint in your OnClickListener to see why it's not working. Since this question already has an accepted answer, I suggest asking again if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use ImageButton in main.xml, fix this;

Main Activity

```
ImageButton imageButtonCamCord = (ImageButton )findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCamCord);
```

if it does not work

Main Activity

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ** don't use


return true;
}
```

Second Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camcord, menu);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_camcord); ** don't use
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
ImageButton imageButtonCamCord = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCamCord);
```

instead of this :

```
Button imageButtonCamCord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCamCord);
```

If it doesn't solve the problem, try to post the Logcat output.